# Why can you not put set comprehension first in this python operation?

Tags: python, set

I have two lists. I am converting both lists to sets and creating a set dictionary like this:

```
friends=["John","bob","Kimbo", "Jacob","Jane"]
time_since_seen=[3,6,1,4,7]

long_timers={
    friends[i]: time_since_seen[i]
    for i in range(len(friends))
    }
```

This may be a dumb question, but why doesn't putting set comprehension first in python work?(switching order of for i... and friends[i]...

```
long_timers={
    for i in range(len(friends))
   friends[i]: time_since_seen[i]
 }
```

This code doesn't work. I apologize if this is a really dumb question, but I am a mechanical engineer and I started learning python 5 days ago.

Comment: 1. That's a dictionary comprehension, not set. 2. The second code does not work because it's an invalid syntax. There isn't really a better explanation

Comment: And FWIW, you don't even need it. `dict(zip(friends, time_since_seen))` works as well

Comment: You aren't putting the dict comprehension first,  the whole thing is a dict comprehension, you are simply using the wrong syntax.

Comment: A comprehension wraps a generator expression (more or less), not a `for` loop. The fact that they share the keyword `for` doesn't make them interchangeable.

Comment: @chepner not *really*. Comprehension constructs are all similar, and a generator expression is a comprehension.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Since you already know the key terms "set", "comprehension" and "dictionary", it should be easy to look up existing reference material to demonstrate the correct syntax for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the python world dear jlifter1

you have to find out how the dict comprehensions work.

dict comprehension syntax is:

```py
{ expression for item in list if conditional }
```

That is equivalent to:

```py
for item in list:
    if conditional:
        expression
```

This is the syntax rule and you can not change it :)

UPDATE:
as you mentioned in your comment you want to do it with for loop.
what you have tried is:

long_timers={ for i in range(len(friends)): friends[i]: time_since_seen[i] }

but it's not correct. you have to write it like this:

```py
long_timers = {}
for i in range(len(friends)):
    long_timers[friends[i]]= time_since_seen[i]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can do the dictionary comprehension, but when it comes to converting it into a for loop:                                                                                   
   long_timers={
  for i in range(len(friends)):
    friends[i]: time_since_seen[i]
  
}                                                                                                                                                     I get an error...

Comment: @jlifter1 I updated my answer please check it. and notice the difference between code order in for loop and dict comprehension

Comment: no problem @jlifter1 . would you please upvote my answer if it was helpful? and select it as the correct answer?

Comment: Would love to. However, my post got -2 votes, and I am unable to post and upvote comments until I get +15 reputation unfortunately.

Comment: @jlifter1no problem. I'm happy I could help you :) good luck with python :)

Answer (score 0):

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is your friend here:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(friends, time_since_seen))
# {'John': 3, 'bob': 6, 'Kimbo': 1, 'Jacob': 4, 'Jane': 7}
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/197f5fc687)

---

Note: [Examples Using Dict Comprehension in Python](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/5-examples-using-dict-comprehension/)

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Not quite my answer, but I just learned zip a few minutes ago, and it does solve the problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

because code goes in order, it reads the first line and executes it first

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I understand python is a sequential language, I am just confused as to why we can't put the for loop statement first...since we are iterating over a range.

Comment: @jlifter1 because *that's the syntax rule*. It isn't a for-loop statement, the whole thing is it's own syntax